# Where to see VESPA feed error detail log?

Tags: vespa

When I feed my file, sometimes "feeder.error.count" will not be zero, like below

```
{
  "feeder.seconds" : 140.016,
  "feeder.ok.count" : 273229,
  "feeder.ok.rate" : 1951.416,
  "feeder.error.count" : 4,
  "feeder.inflight.count" : 85,
  "http.request.count" : 273364,
  "http.request.bytes" : 580306750,
  "http.exception.count" : 6,
  "http.response.count" : 273273,
  "http.response.bytes" : 24604630,
  "http.response.error.count" : 44,
  "http.response.latency.millis.min" : 2.000,
  "http.response.latency.millis.avg" : 76.000,
  "http.response.latency.millis.max" : 758.000,
  "http.response.code.counts" : {
    "502" : 44,
    "200" : 273229
  }
}
```

Where can I see the detail information ?   to check which data cause the error count added

And if the feeding file is too small, there is no any log showed on screen,
is there any log file can check feeding result ?

Answer (score 3):

Use the `--show-errors` flag which the client supports https://docs.vespa.ai/en/vespa-feed-client.html

```
./vespa-feed-client-cli/vespa-feed-client --help
usage: vespa-feed-client <options>
Vespa feed client
    --benchmark                           Print statistics to stdout when
                                          done
    --ca-certificates <arg>               Path to file containing CA X.509
                                          certificates encoded as PEM
    --certificate <arg>                   Path to PEM encoded X.509
                                          certificate file
    --connections <arg>                   Number of concurrent HTTP/2
                                          connections
    --disable-ssl-hostname-verification   Disable SSL hostname
                                          verification
    --dryrun                              Enable dryrun mode where each
                                          operation succeeds after 1ms
    --endpoint <arg>                      URI to feed endpoint
    --file <arg>                          Path to feed file in JSON format
    --header <arg>                        HTTP header on the form 'Name:
                                          value'
    --help
    --max-failure-seconds <arg>           Exit if specified number of
                                          seconds ever pass without any
                                          successful operations. Disabled
                                          by default
    --max-streams-per-connection <arg>    Maximum number of concurrent
                                          streams per HTTP/2 connection
    --private-key <arg>                   Path to PEM/PKCS#8 encoded
                                          private key file
    --proxy <arg>                         URI to proxy endpoint
    --route <arg>                         Target Vespa route for feed
                                          operations
    --show-all                            Print the result of every feed
                                          operation
    --show-errors                         Print every feed operation
                                          failure
    --silent                              Disable periodic status printing
                                          to stderr
    --stdin                               Read JSON input from standard
                                          input
    --timeout <arg>                       Feed operation timeout (in
                                          seconds)
    --trace <arg>                         The trace level of network
                                          traffic. Disabled by default
                                          (=0)
    --verbose                             Print stack traces on errors
    --version
```